# Reading video from OpenMV H7 camera over ttyACM0 port using c++ code

Tags: opencv, openmv

I have an OpenMV H7 camera who's output I need to read into OpenCV. Now, the serial output is ttyACM0 where I am able to stream image frames. How can I read these frames in c++ code? I cannot use `cv::VideoCapture()` as the camera is not recognized as a video device. Serial libraries for C++ that I've found so far are quite messy. I am able to do this on python using `serial` library. Any help in reading into c++ would be valuable.

Comment: How do you access the images using python? In C++ you can just `open` the `/dev/ttyACM0` device and read/write from/to it as if it would be a normal file.

Comment: Yes, but I'm unable to find any good resources for help. It would be great if you could point me to somewhere reliable.

Comment: What about the Library for the Camera? Source code is publicly available.